# Different gearman libraries for any language

Tags: java, php, c, linux, gearman

I'm working on making a presentation about gearman, and wondering if anyone knows any examples for languages other than PHP for registering functions.

Basically I'm looking for an equilivant in any language of the following:

```
$gm = new GearmanWorker();
$gm->addFunction('reverse', function(GearmanJob $job){
    return strrev($job->workload());
});
while(1){ $gm->work(); }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there no examples in the Gearman documentation?

Comment: Not really. The only one I found so far is the simple 'reverse' example on the gearman.org website, but it's only in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The java-gearman-service has an example here:
http://code.google.com/p/java-gearman-service/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fexamples%2Fecho

There are some examples packaged with the C version:
https://launchpad.net/gearmand

Answer (score 0):

Basic examples for

Ruby
Python
PHP

can be also found at: 
[http://gearmanhq.com](http://gearmanhq.com/help/tutorials/)

Perl examples you can always found at http://search.cpan.org/, search for Gearman.